# How to assign different color to each node on a sunburst?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, sunburst-diagram

I am creating a sunburst for big data. To make it more readable, I need to assign different color for each node (ideally different shades of the same color for every subtree).

I've already tried with :

```
 d3.scaleSequential()
 d3.scale.ordinal()
 d3.scale.category20c()
```

I think it can work but I am not sure where to put it exactly. For the moment it works only with one color for every subtree.

```
 var width = 500;
 var height = 500;
 var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
 var color = d3.scaleSequential().domain([1,10]).interpolator(d3.interpolateViridis);

 var g = d3.select('svg')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

 var partition = d3.partition() //.layout
   .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);


 d3.json("file:///c:\\Users\\c1972519\\Desktop\\Stage\\tests_diagrams\\figure_4.8_ex3\\data2.json", function(error, nodeData){
       if (error) throw error;

       var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
         .sum(function(d){
             return d.size;
           });

       partition(root);
       var arc = d3.arc()
         .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x0; })
         .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x1; })
         .innerRadius(function(d) { return d.y0; })
         .outerRadius(function(d) { return d.y1; });

       var arcs = g.selectAll('g')
         .data(root.descendants())
         .enter()
         .append('g')
         .attr("class", "node")
         .append('path')
         .attr("display", function (d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
         .attr("d", arc)
         .style('stroke', '#fff')
         .style("fill", function(d){return color(d)});
 }
```

So I would like to have different shade on every subtree to make it more readable.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with scaleLinear.

var x = d3.scaleLinear([10, 130], [0, 960]);

```
 or
```

var color = d3.scaleLinear([10, 100], ["brown", "steelblue"]);

**Example:**

https://bl.ocks.org/starcalibre/6cccfa843ed254aa0a0d

**Documentation:**
https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear

Linear Scales

## d3.scaleLinear([[domain, ]range]) <>

Constructs a new continuous scale with the specified domain and range, the default interpolator and clamping disabled. If either domain or range are not specified, each defaults to [0, 1]. Linear scales are a good default choice for continuous quantitative data because they preserve proportional differences. Each range value y can be expressed as a function of the domain value x: y = mx + b.